# Sending curl like request in golang

Tags: json, curl, go

I try send request like this in golang but with no result:

```
curl -s -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm?type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2"
```

How to do that?

I want to send data do Domoticz Home Automation System.
Anser I got:

```
{
   "status" : "ERR"
}
```

but should be:

```
{
"status" : "OK",
"title" : "Update Device"
}
```

I try this code:

```
    b := bytes.NewBufferString("type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2")
    res, _ := http.Post("http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm", "Accept: application/json", b)
```

Comment: See https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/

Comment: What do you mean "no result"? Your question includes a result.

Comment: Your curl example uses GET with a query string, your Go example uses POST with a body. They aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in your initial `curl` command, you missed the `-X POST` parameter.
The [generated code](https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/) would then be:

```
// Generated by curl-to-Go: https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm?type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2", nil)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your curl command and Go code are almost completely unalike.

1. Your Go sends a POST request, and curl a GET request.
2. Your curl command sets an Accept header, your Go code doesn't.
3. Your Go command sends a body, your curl command doesn't.
4. Your curl command sends URL parameters, your Go code doesn't.

Your go code does the curl equivalent of:

```
curl -s -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" "http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm" -d "type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2"
```

The simplest way to emulate your curl command in Go is:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm?type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
    b := bytes.NewBufferString(" ")
    res, _ := http.Post("http://192.168.1.183:8080/json.htm?type=command&c=getauth&param=udevice&idx=9&nvalue=0&svalue=10;43;2", "Accept: application/json", b)
```

but I think it is not best way to do that.